# Snappy Html To Pdf - Symfony 4 - Css not loaded - Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony4, webpack-encore, knp-snappy

I try to use this bundle :

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

And generate my html with css, now assetic bundle is deprecated with Symfony 4 dans when i try to loaded css like that :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works in the Controller / View Context but not when a i generate html to pdf the css is not loaded :/

I suppose it's because there is interpretation of my app.js to load app.scss but i dont konw how to solve this problem.

Thx by advance

Answer (score 1):

I have the same pobleme.
What i understand, Wkhtmltopdf embed a regular css file into the pdf. Because webpack (for me) use an external server, to serve file (eg: localhost:8080). Wkhtmltopdf (and snappy) cant embed it.

For my tests, if I create a normal css file and link it like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('pdf/pdf.css')) }}">
```

My styles are here.

I think we should find a way to copy pre-proccessed file into web/public folder

Comment: This method is quite good as a webpack workaround in Symfony 4.1 when using knp-snappy.